# Retrieve Rows if Current Time is in between the Start and End Time in Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

If I run the query

```
SELECT curtime(), concat(START_HOUR,':00:00'), concat(END_HOUR,':00:00') from table_name;
```

I get the following result

> 10:30:50  |   1:00:00  |  12:00:00
>
> 10:30:50  |   1:00:00  |  12:00:00

But when I try to retrieve rows if current time is in between the START_HOUR and END_HOUR (`the START_HOUR and END_HOUR are INT(2)`) It returns 0 rows.

I tried the following queries and none worked

```
SELECT curtime(), concat(START_HOUR,':00:00'), concat(END_HOUR,':00:00') from table_name WHERE curtime() >=concat(START_HOUR,':00:00') && curtime()<=concat(END_HOUR,':00:00');

SELECT curtime(), concat(START_HOUR,':00:00'), concat(END_HOUR,':00:00') from table_name WHERE curtime() BETWEEN concat(START_HOUR,':00:00') AND concat(END_HOUR,':00:00');

SELECT curtime(), concat(START_HOUR,':00:00'), concat(END_HOUR,':00:00') from table_name WHERE concat(curtime(),'') >=concat(START_HOUR,':00:00') && concat(curtime(),'')<=concat(END_HOUR,':00:00');

SELECT curtime(), concat(START_HOUR,':00:00'), concat(END_HOUR,':00:00') from table_name WHERE concat(curtime(),'') BETWEEN concat(START_HOUR,':00:00') AND concat(END_HOUR,':00:00');

SELECT curtime(), concat(START_HOUR,':00:00'), concat(END_HOUR,':00:00') from table_name WHERE CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i'), ':00') >=concat(START_HOUR,':00:00') && CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i'), ':00')<=concat(END_HOUR,':00:00');
```

and all the combinations of these.

Please help me find out what I am doing wrong and how I can retrieve the desired records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `CAST` the time values into TIME types.

```
SELECT 
    curtime(), 
    CAST(concat(START_HOUR,':00:00') as TIME), 
    CAST(concat(END_HOUR,':00:00') as TIME)
FROM table_name WHERE 
    CURTIME() BETWEEN 
        CAST(CONCAT(START_HOUR,":00:00") AS TIME) AND 
        CAST(CONCAT(END_HOUR,":00:00") AS TIME)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are doing comparision with curtime(), try to CAST your string as Time first.

Try following:

```
SELECT colums FROM table WHERE curtime() < CAST(concate(START_HOUR,'00:00') AS time) AND curtime() > CAST(concate(END_HOUR,'00:00') AS time);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just compare the hours

```
SELECT curtime(), concat(START_HOUR,':00:00'), concat(END_HOUR,':00:00') from oknot_ad_agreements 
WHERE HOUR(curtime()) >= START_HOUR && HOUR(curtime()) <= END_HOUR;
```